# How to parse the following text file into class?

Tags: c++

I have the following class

```
class Film {
    Person authors[5]; //This will actually include only the director
    string title;
    string producer;
    int n_authors;
    int year;
    int running_time;
    Person actors[5];
    int n_actors;
}
```

And the following file format (don't ask me why I use this, I MUST use this format)

```
Stanley
Kubrick  
#          
2001: A Space Odissey
*
1968
161
Keir
Dullea
Gary 
Lockwood
#
```

The `#` indicates the end of a list (in this case a 'Person' class), while the `*` a missing field (in this case the producer, btw the `producer` field must be filled with an `*` in the class).
The class `Person` consists of `Name` and `Surname` and has an overloaded `operator >>` that calls:

```
void load(ifstream& in) {
    getline(in,name);
    getline(in,surname);
}
```

What's the best method to parse this file structure? I can't use regular expressions or anything more advanced than ifstream. My concern is on how (and where in the code) to detect the end of file and the end of a list of people.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: I would begin by describing the grammar in EBNF (or PEG). It does not seem like you have a clear idea what the structure of the file is.

Comment: Tell your teacher about [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) :)

Comment: Will this file contain data for one file only, or there can be data for multiple films also? Secondly can we expect * for authors and actors field? Please clarify Stanley is Name and Kubrick is Surname, right?

Comment: The file will contain a list of films, stored just one after another (no delimiter). We can expect * for any non int field (for int fields 0 means not set), and Stanley is name and Kubrick Surname.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard line reading idiom:

```
#include <fstream>   // for std::ifstream
#include <sstream>   // for std::istringstream
#include <string>    // for std::string and std::getline

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        // process line
    }
}
```

Where it says "process line" you should add some logic that tracks the current state of the parser.

For your simple application you could proceed in bits, reading lists and tokens as specified by the format. For instance:

```
std::vector<std::string> read_list(std::istream & in)
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        if (line == "#") { return result; }
        result.push_back(std::move(line));
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Unterminated list");
}
```

Now you can say:

```
std::string title, producer, token3, token4, token5, token6;

std::vector<std::string> authors = read_list(infile);

if (!(std::getline(infile, title)    &&
      std::getline(infile, producer) &&
      std::getline(infile, token3)   &&
      std::getline(infile, token4)   &&
      std::getline(infile, token5)     ) )
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid file format");
}

std::vector<std::string> actors = read_list(infile);
```

You can use `std::stoi` to convert tokens 3 – 5 to integers:

```
int year = std::stoi(token4);
int runtime = std::stoi(token5);
```

Note that the `n_authors` and `n_actors` variables are redundant, since you have self-terminated lists already. You can or should use the variables as an integrity check if you like.

Comment: So it is inproper to overload the ifstream >> operator for the class Film and Person and it is better to process the lines in the main function?

Comment: @Pincopallino: Not at all - you're most welcome to wrap all this into a separate function which you call from an overloaded `>>` operator. In that case, make sure you store the values in temporary variables and set the stream error flags when needed, and only copy the results if the entire operation succeeds.

Comment: And how do I check the eof, given that is `Person` the first class that will reach the end of file?

Comment: @Pincopallino: You don't need to. The entire extraction operation either succeeds or it doesn't. When it doesn't, you stop extracting.

Comment: @Pincopallino: Coming to think of it, I wouldn't overload `<<` after all. It's confusing, because we're doing multiline parsing. Better to have a function `std::istream & getfilm(std::istream &, Film &)`, much like `std::getline`, so you can say `while (getfilm(infile, f)) { /*...*/ }`